# Need to modify Stack/Linked List program to determine if a word is a palindrome

Tags: c++

So I wrote a program that implements a stack class as a linked list. So far, the program takes whatever string the user enters, and successfully places each char in the stack (at least I think it does). What I need to know is how I can go through each character and determine whether or not the string is a palindrome. Any tips?

Here's my code so far:

Main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include "stack.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){
Stack o;
cout << "Enter a string" << endl;
string word;
cin >> word;
o.divide_String(word);

o.Print();

return 0;
}
```

Header:

```
#ifndef STACKS_H
#define STACKS_H
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Stack{
private:

    typedef struct item{    
        char letter;
        item* prev;
    }* itemPtr;
    itemPtr stackPtr;   


public:
    Stack();    
    void Push(char letter); 
    void Pop(); 
    void ReadItem(item* r); 
    void Print();   
    void Stack::divide_String(string s);
    ~Stack();   

};

#endif
```

Function Definitions:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include "stack.h"




using namespace std;

Stack::Stack(){
    stackPtr = NULL;
}

Stack::~Stack(){    
    itemPtr p1;
    itemPtr p2;

    p1 = stackPtr;  
    while(p1 != NULL){   
        p2 = p1;        
        p1 = p1->prev;  
        delete p2;      
    }
}

void Stack::Push(char letter){
    itemPtr n = new item;       
    n->letter = letter;         

    if(stackPtr == NULL){       
        stackPtr = n;           
        stackPtr->prev = NULL;  
    }
    else{                      
        n->prev = stackPtr;
        stackPtr = n;
    }
}

void Stack::Pop(){              
    if(stackPtr == NULL){       
        cout << "There is nothing on the stack." << endl;
    }
    else{       
        itemPtr p = stackPtr;   
        ReadItem(p);            
        stackPtr = stackPtr->prev;  
        p->prev = NULL;         
        delete p;               
    }
}

void Stack::ReadItem(item* r){  
    cout << r->letter;
}

void Stack::Print(){
    itemPtr x = stackPtr;   
    cout << "Current Stack: " << endl;
    while(x != NULL){       
        ReadItem(x);        
        x = x->prev;
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void Stack::divide_String(string s){
    for(char &c : s){
        Push(c);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few pointers:

- This is not too different from using a stack to validate parentheses in an expression.
- Half the characters in a palindrome should exactly match the other half in reverse. Since a stack is LIFO, this comparison becomes much easier.
- You'll need to take into account what happens if there are an odd number of characters in the string, hence not giving you a clean half

Hope this helps.

PS: Not putting any code down, since I'd encourage you to try and solve the problem. There are a few different ways to do it.